# Subtracting two columns to give a new column in R

Tags: r, syntax

Hello I´am trying to subtract the column `B` from column `A` in a `dat` matrix to create a `C` column  (`A` - `B`):

My input:

```
A  B
1  2
2  2
3  2
4  2
```

My expected output:

```
A  B  C
1  2 -1
2  2  0
3  2  1
4  2  2
```

I have tried: `dat$C <- (dat$A - dat$B)`, but I get a: `## $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors`error

Cheers.

Comment: If you really mean a matrix you'll need `input[,"B"] - input[,"A"]`  or possibly use direct indexing: `input[,2] - input[,1]` if A and B are the first two columns.  The syntax you are using is for `data frames`.  You can do `str(input)` to see what it is if you are not certain.

Comment: @BryanHanson I apologize for supplying the answer when you placed this comment, I just didn't see it.

Comment: No worries. Looks like they have their answer.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

As @Bryan Hanson was saying in the above comment, your syntax and data organization relates more to a data frame. I would treat your data as a data frame and simply use the syntax you provided earlier:

```
> data <- data.frame(A = c(1,2,3,4), B = c(2,2,2,2))
> data$C <- (data$A - data$B)
> data
  A B  C
1 1 2 -1
2 2 2  0
3 3 2  1
4 4 2  2
```

Comment: With the data transformed to dataframe I am getting this error: `## - makes no sense to factors`  Some idea of the problem source?

Comment: You should post `dput(head(str(your_data)))` so we can see what you are working with, otherwise we have to guess which is not a good use of time.  Add that to your original post.

Answer (score 4):

Yes right, If you really mean a matrix, you can see this example

```
> x <- matrix(data=1:3,nrow=4,ncol=3)
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    3
[2,]    2    3    1
[3,]    3    1    2
[4,]    1    2    3
> x[,3] = x[,1]-x[,2]
> x
     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2   -1
[2,]    2    3   -1
[3,]    3    1    2
[4,]    1    2   -1
>
```

Answer (score 0):

However, one should absolutely point out here that matrix operations in R don't abide by the usual linear algebra closure.

```
> x[,3]-x[,1]
[1]  2 -1 -1  2
> is.matrix(x[,3]-x[,1])
[1] FALSE
```

Further, one more directly anticipates a column vector which can be obtained by applying the matrix transpose TWICE (which is weird in itself) with the first one casting the output as a matrix.

```
> t(t(x[,3]-x[,1]))
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]   -1
[3,]   -1
[4,]    2
```

Or one can use the drop=FALSE option:

```
>x[,3,drop=FALSE] - x[,1,drop=FALSE]
     [,1]
[1,]    2
[2,]   -1
[3,]   -1
[4,]    2
```

Behavior of 2D slices From 3D array are fine though.